# CakePHP 2 - single core, two apps, one inside the other?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm fairly new to CakePHP and am trying to setup a custom admin area for my app. I realize Cake can create an [admin area with scaffolding](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/scaffolding.html#creating-a-simple-admin-interface-with-scaffolding) but I'd like to build something much more customized, and have it accessible from via `/admin/`, with one app for the public side and another for the admin.

Ideally, the structure would be:

```
www
^- apples (public application here)
   ^- apples-admin (password-protected control panel)
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set this up using a single Cake core and two apps - one for "apples" and one for "apples-admin". I've read some notes about modding PHP's include path, but that won't be possible in the production environment. The other notes I see about changing CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH aren't very clear on where I would make that change, and it doesn't appear as though that would get me the app-inside-app structure I'm after.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Am I better off using just a single app for both the public side and admin area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using a single application.

To get up and running:

Use [Prefix Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) to map your admin actions.

Then use the [Auth component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) to restrict access to your '**admin**' actions. I recommend setting up a **User** model to manage your users and using the [FormAuthentication](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/form-authenticate) handler for logging in.

If you haven't used [Bake](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) for code generation before, then that's also worth looking into. It'll help create a base starting point for a lot of your admin functions.

Good luck.